# How do you run War files generated by Gradle War plugin on IDE?

Tags: gradle, ide, war

How do you run War files generated by Gradle War plug-in on IDE?
How to configure the IDE to run the file on its own? 
Intellij IDEA can do it. I just need to configure it for 'gradle war' and deploy the output.

Comment: The answer is likely correct, but it's helpful to understand that a WAR file requires a WAR container to run.  that stands for "Web Application Archive".  This refers to something based on the Java Servlets specification, or even the Java Enterprise Edition specification(s). Two very common "WAR containers" are Jetty and Tomcat.  Other "JEE" containers are WebLogic, WebSphere, and others.

Comment: But I need eclipse to do the job, not Gradle.

Comment: Run a google search for "Run jetty in eclipse" or "run tomcat in eclipse".

Comment: But I do not need these. The question is not about that. I do need to run 'gradle war' in eclipse and then deploy **without a Gradle plug-in**. as not Gradle should deploy- it is a build tool, not a deploy tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply "Jetty" plugin to your project:

`apply plugin: 'jetty'`

after that, task `jettyRunWar` will be available. It will run your war from commandline or IDE.